# What is M2M Mihini framework?

Tags: eclipse, lua

I was reading about Machine to Machine(M2M) technology where it was mentioned that Mihini is the framework that will be used to create M2M applications. My doubt is,

1. How to integrate the Mihini framework in Koneki Lua Development environment.
2. How to use that framework.
3. Has Mihini framework is released for use.
4. Is there tutorials available to use Mihini framework in Koneki.

Comment: there is no real question here

Answer (score 2):

The Mihini code is hopefully going to be posted on eclipse.org this week. It has been undergoing our normal IP due diligence, so sorry for the delay.

In the meantime, there is a little documentation on how to get going with Koneki and Mihini on this page[1]. I've been playing with this stuff in the evenings and hope to be able to add some more content there soon.

Please be patient for just a little bit longer :)

[1] http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mihini/Run_Mihini_on_an_Open_Hardware_platform